# Can you import a SSL certificate from another Windows IIS 7 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

Usually I re-request the CSR and install the certificate when I move servers.

Was hoping if there was a faster way, where I can just export/import a SSL certificate when I move my website to another server.

I am using Windows Server 2008 (R2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are viewing your SSL Certificates in the IIS Management Console, right-click the certificate and choose `Export...`

You can then export a `.pfx` file. You will need to specify a password for it.

On your new server, simply go to the Server Certificates page and choose `Import...`, select the `.pfx` file from the previous server, enter your password, and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a certificate's public and private key is built into Windows, as long as you imported the certificate with the "Allow Export" flag set...  In case you have a certificate that doesn't allow you to export the private key you can use a third party tool to extract the private key...

iSEC Partners wrote a tool called [Jailbreak](https://www.isecpartners.com/jailbreak.html) that allows you to export "locked" certificates...  I wrote up a review of it on [my blog](http://www.dscoduc.com/2009/07/private-keys-unexportable/)...

Answer (score 0):

1) Simple .pfx export:

Open IIS Manager, click on your server in the left-hand pane (just below Start Page), double click Server Certificates in the main pane, select the desired certificate and click Export in the right-hand actions (or right-click the certificate). This method thanks to this link
http://aaronwalrath.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/export-ssl-certificate-signed-by-public-certificate-authority-to-new-iis-7-5-server/

2) Another way which brings up a few different options for the export format including .cer (DER or Base-64 encodings for X.509) and .p7b:

Edit the HTTPS site binding, clicking View next to the selected SSL certificate, click the Details tab, select Copy to File. This brings up the Certificate Export Wizard and just follow your nose from there.