# IIS, SSL with client certs on web farm

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

We're building a web service that will be deployed on an IIS 7.5 farm, and secured through SSL, and also requiring client certs that will be mapped to Active Directory accounts.

My understanding is that the server cert needs to be generated for a specific server.  If that is the case then we will need a server cert for each server in the farm.  Because the farm will be load balanced,  how do we generate client certs that will work with any of the servers in the farm?

Comment: The last sentence make it unclear if you want information about client certs, server certs or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the certificate successfully installed on the first server (the signed cert bound to your CSR). You can then just export the entire certificate and then import it into the remaining servers. There are a ton of existing resources online for the details on how to export and import certificates so I'll skip that here. But here is a link to another article on here to get you started if you need:

[Can you import a SSL certificate from another Windows IIS](https://serverfault.com/q/122299/142224)

Comment: Also a wildcard cert would work as well